# How to add more than one tabs to a single facebook page by sdk in php

Tags: php

I am using sdk and want to add multiple tabs in my admin panel but I am not able to do so can someone help.
As Iam having my own admin panel I want to create exactly like woobox so that i can add tabs and url to pages.

Comment: Your question does not have enough info to see what trouble you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Their is no way to add multiple tab to facebook page by a single facebook app we can add only one tab by one facebook  app.If you want to add multiple tab you have to create multiple facebook app.